# How to sort similar objets in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

[image]

[image]

picture 1 is the data frame that i want to modify.
and I want to modify it in a way that values of column C corresponding to similar objects of column B should arrange in ascending order.

this is what i have tried so far:

```
summarize (df$V2, order(df$V2, descending=FALSE))
```

Comment: `df[order(df[,2]),]`

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this :

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data %>% 
  select(-A) %>% 
  group_by(B) %>%
  arrange(B, C) %>% 
  bind_cols(data[, 1]) %>% 
  select(A, everything()) %>% 
  ungroup()
df

# A tibble: 7 x 3
  A     B         C
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 a1    M_01    191
2 a2    M_01    199
3 b1    M_01    232
4 c1    M_02    324
5 c1    M_02    433
6 d1    M_03    164
7 d2    M_04    288
```

#### Data

```
data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~A, ~B, ~C,
  "a1", "M_01", 232,
  "a2", "M_01", 191,
  "b1", "M_01", 199,
  "c1", "M_02", 433,
  "c1", "M_02", 324,
  "d1", "M_03", 164,
  "d2", "M_04", 288,
)
data

# A tibble: 7 x 3
  A     B         C
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 a1    M_01    232
2 a2    M_01    191
3 b1    M_01    199
4 c1    M_02    433
5 c1    M_02    324
6 d1    M_03    164
7 d2    M_04    288
```

Comment: this code is not working. it is just arranging whole column c in ascending order